# How can I forward Google Voice to my iPhone but still use the iPhone's visual voicemail?

Tags: iphone, google-voice

I have a Google voice number which forwards to my iPhone's number. I'm wondering if there's any way to make AT&T handle the voicemail rather than Google Voice. This way I will be able to use the Phone app to view voicemails rather than having to open a browser with Google Voice.

I understand that if I use it this way I won't get transcribed voicemail. That's fine, that's not the reason I'm using Google Voice.

Ideally I want Google Voice to handle voicemail when my phone is off or in airplane mode, and when my phone is on and I have a signal, I want it to use my phone's answering machine. This way I get notified of voicemail via WiFi when airplane mode is on, but when my cell signal is on, I get to use the nicer interface of the Phone app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, the iPhone's voice-mail system *must* pick up the call before the Google Voice voice-mail system does.

> If you don't respond to a call within 25 seconds (by accepting, sending to voicemail, listening in on voicemail, or accepting and recording the call), Google Voice will send the caller to Google voicemail.
>
> [Source](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115110)

You can set your iPhone to ring from 5-30 seconds (unless it has been changed since I've looked at this).  The default is 20 seconds I think - have you previously lengthened it?

[This page](http://iphoneguru.org/change-the-amount-of-rings-before-visual-voicemail-answers) has instructions on how to change the length.